# Custom UISLider , setThumbImageForState changes

Tags: ios6, uislider

This is screen shot of the control... http://www.flickr.com/photos/87673882@N02/8025480151/in/photostream

This is a custom slider that look like in highlighted and normal state..

This, control is working fine upto ios5.1 ,but from ios6 the program is going in infinite loop. can anyone explain me this problem and suggest a solution...

You can browse my code at

https://github.com/SandeepDhull1990/TVCalibratedSlider

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. Check the git repository mentioned above.